# Finding Decimal in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am having a string like this:

> Thank you for paying your Insurance bill of Rs 5896.48. Your
>   transaction number for this payment is 981562359815. Your card will be
>   debited on 2020-07-15.

I need to extract decimals of transaction number alone using regex. Count of decimals may vary time to time.

```
Pattern.compile("(?i)(transaction number *?)(.+?)(\\.)")
```

Using the above patter I tried to extract but I can't successful with this approach. Is there any efficient approach?

Comment: If you know that the transaction number is preceded with the text: "Your transaction number for this payment is " you can use `indexOf()`. If not, can you assume that all transaction numbers are of length 12 ?

Comment: It is funny how people who don't have the slightest idea how to do something insist on an *efficient* approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there may be no dot (`.`) between the string `transaction number` and the number you're searching for, use

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?i)transaction number [^.]*\\b(\\d+)\\.");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?i)    # case insensitive matching mode
transaction\ number  # Match this literal text
[^.]*   # Match any number of characters except dots
\b      # Match the position at the start of a number
(\d+)   # Match a number (1 digit or more), capture the result in group 1
\.      # Match a dot
```

If you simply want to find the very first number after `transaction number`, then use

```
Pattern.compile("(?i)transaction number\\D*(\\d+)")
```

`\D` matches any character that is not a digit.

Comment: Then you just need to access the contents of group 1 after the match. Editing my answer...

Comment: Suppose if i don't have dot at the end of  '981562359815', is there any thing to get first decimal sequence instead of last.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 s = s.replaceAll(".* is (\\d+).*", "$1");
```